# Sybase - join doesn't work properly

Tags: sql, join, sybase

I've got a problem. I'm using sybase at my school, and when I'm making my project I see a few problems. I learnt that `join` without `on` clause should work like `cross join` (cartesian product). But when I'm doing `join` between two tables, `A` and `B` for example.

```
Select * from A join B
```

works exactly the same as `A join B on A.Key=B.key`. I have to use cross join to have cartesian.

And I have another question: I should be able to `join` tables without any relations and get cartesian product of them but instead I see "there is no way to `join` table `X` to `Y`".

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a moment to read over [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `Select * from A join B`  is invalid SQL and won't run at all.

Comment: Can You tell me why ? It's simply working at other systems.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently on the Sybase system you're using, `join` without `on` means a "natural join": one that implies a join based on columns of the same name (or, maybe, following foreign key declarations).

> I learnt that join without on clause should work like cross join

In the early days, SQL had no *join* keyword.  Your query would have  been expressed as `Select * from A, B`.  That produced a cartesian product.  From a relational perspective, that product was winnowed with a relational *select* (restrict) operator, using `where`.

Comment: Ok, this is what i noticed. When I'm using query You described  `Select *  from A,B`, i have cartesian product, but when i'm using join without on clause i have the same results like with on clause but when i i've got more than one columns matching i see warning "there is more than one way to join " I guess that Sybase is just smart because i checked this problem at other system, and Join without on clause gave me cartesian . Thanks for help, I will write my sql code like it should be done with every clause needed, I think it's bad idea to let system doing it for you , it can be misleading.